# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when executing linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I'm writing a program that adds a series of integers to a move-to-front list (implemented with a linked list). Then, it takes another set of integers which the program is supposed to search for within the linked list. If the program finds the integer it's looking for, the number is moved to the front of the linked list.

I'm having an error when EX_BAD_ACCESS error when I run my search method:

```
void P1LinkedList::search(const int &query){
    iterator itr = begin();

//erases current position, inserts found number to front, increments traversal count
    for(int i = 0; i < theSize; i++){
        if(query == itr.current->data){

            push_front(query);
            erase(itr);
        }
        theTraversalCount++;
        itr++;
    }
}
```

The error happens at the `if` statement within the `for` loop. With `itr.current->data` I'm trying to get the integer held by the node that itr is pointing to, but XCode is telling me that the node is null.

Also, here is my implementation of the iterator class:

```
#include"iterator.h"

    iterator::iterator(Node *p) 
        :const_iterator{p}{}

    int& iterator::operator*(){
        return const_iterator::retrieve(); 
    }

    const int& iterator::operator*() const{
        return const_iterator::operator*(); 
    }

    iterator& iterator::operator++(){
        this ->current = this->current->next; 
        return *this; 
    }

    iterator iterator::operator++(int){
            iterator old = *this; 
            ++(*this); 
            return old; 
    } 

    iterator iterator::operator--(){
        this->current = this->current->prev;
        return(*this); 
    }
```

And this is the method that calls upon `search()`:

```
void completeQueries(const std::string & queries, P1LinkedList & myList){
    std::istringstream iss(queries);

    for(int i=0; i < 100; i++){
        int val;
        iss >> val;
        myList.search(val);
    }
}
```

Edit:

Here is my erase() method:

```
iterator P1LinkedList::erase(iterator itr){
    Node* p = itr.current; 
    iterator retVal{p->next}; 
    return nullptr; 
}
```

Comment: I suppose you need to make a check `if (itr != end()) { ... }` in your for loop

Comment: `P1LinkedList::search(const int &query)` why would you ever pass a plain `int` as a `const &`? At best it makes no difference, at worst it makes your code slower by adding indirection. Just pass such primitive types by value.

Comment: @JesperJuhl ...[slower by adding indirection] and potential for aliasing :)

Comment: @Max that as well..

Comment: You need to show how `erase` is implemented. But if it's anything like `std::list`, then `erase(itr)` invalidates `itr`. For `std::list` it would be more correct to do `itr = erase(itr);`, but that alone won't fix the problem (because the number of times you are allowed to increment `it` depends on whether the value is found or not).

Comment: So your `erase` method does not actually erase (or delete) anything, does not modify the list, does not change `itr` and always returns `iterator(nullptr)`? What's the point of calling it?

Comment: Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `EX_BAD_ACCESS` means you are horribly abusing a pointer somewhere in your code.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I realized I didn't finish implementing erase. Thanks for pointing this out!